# A software that convert sound into Hertz value

Tags: software-development, music, audio, media-converter

I would like to analyze the notes of a song to convert it into the waveform or in Hertz value.

The goal is to preserve these notes as they are, with no change of vibration, without having to correct each individual note toward the european system.

Therefore, the software should read the file and give a result in Hertz value.

Berhane

Comment: Any OS preferences?

Comment: If it can resolve the issue, both Win and Mac programs are good. The preferred platform could be Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert music (MP3) into hertz values (text)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3018/convert-music-mp3-into-hertz-values-text)

Comment: @Fractaliste I **think** that the other is slightly different - and Berhane explains the difference in a [comment there](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3018/convert-music-mp3-into-hertz-values-text#comment5940_3018)

Comment: Dear Nick, as you mentioned, the previouse statement was changed various times, that makes litlle difficult to understand major linkage of thoughts.

Comment: You've asked three variants of this question now and it is still not clear at all. You really need to stop and think about what you want. You've done a lot of writing in the comments below. Now put a similar amount of effort into explaining what you want in your question, instead of complaining because you got an answer that didn't match the requirements that were in your head but not written out.

Comment: Furthermore, comments are not a place for extended conversation. If you need to leave feedback, write **one** comment. Focus your thoughts, and make an effort to be comprehensible.

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is probably a [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), or "Frequency Analysis".

[Audacity](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/plot_spectrum.html) can do this, with the `Analyze -> Plot Spectrum…` tool.

[image]

This will output a graph, and you simply find where it peaks to ascertain the Hertz value of whatever sound you were analyzing. This of course only works if the tone is constant.

If your sound file consists of multiple frequencies (pitches) in sequence, then you're likely going to need to get into customized programming of a tool called [Max/MSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_(software)) or something similar, depending on what you're actually trying to do.

If it's not apparent already, a single-in single-out program that takes a piece of music or arbitrary recorded sound and outputs a single Hertz value would not be a useful program. At best, it would be an average frequency value for the entire clip, and if that's really what you need, you should look into automating one of the options above.

---

**Programmatic transcription of recorded sound to Hz values:**

(only reliable for music with a single line melody in a clear recording)

1. Take as input a waveform, consisting of +/- amplitude over time.
2. Decide on a temporal resolution with which to analyze the waveform, *n* seconds.
3. Break the sound file into *n*-second-long chunks, and run an FFT on each chunk
4. Find the peak frequency for each FFT curve
5. Transform your results into frequency over time
6. Design logic to decide how to break this frequency curve up into "notes".

Comment: As you said the Audocity software presents the Spectrum. However, the Hz value that it is a calculate field from the Spectrum is not edited it. My request is: how will I get the notes that represent their hertz values.
Let say the song has only 5 notes, I expect the result written in Hz value. These 5 notes can be: "A C G B D" or "La Do Sol Si Re" as a result the software should give the output in their Hz value.
I expect to know whether a Software or Programming of "java or else" are available in the market, or Universities have the solution.
I appreciated your kindness.

Comment: The reference you brought that there is no need to list all notes, is right. I expect only the average of it.

Comment: Sorry, but the second sentence of your comment is not syntactically meaningful; I still don't understand what, mathematically, you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps if you elaborate on what you plan to do with this program, it will become clearer? If you already know the note names, the frequencies can be easily calculated programmatically in your own code: http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html

Comment: Dear Reilingh, the explanation you've given are right. you looked into the scientific view. I am focussing on solving issues. I want to do a research. I like to find values or data in order to see the difference among listed notes that exist in a song. My goal is to catch the notes of the song. Meaning get the results in numbers (hz value). From this output I can do the reference I want to pursue. And this is: fetch the sound from any song. (No need to correct the notes into standard pitches). Then list them in a Excel/Word file. From the list data i will construct the module, the theory.

Comment: Finding all of the notes in a song in Hertz value is an equally difficult problem as finding all of the notes in a song by pitch letter name. The fact that you are using a numerical symbology does not change the problem.

Comment: Let me pose it this way -- if you recorded yourself humming the first phrase of "Ode to Joy", that's 15 notes in the space of about 8 seconds, would the program output 15 different Hz values, or just 1?

Comment: Dear Reiligh - you are right, knowing the hz value and the sound itself doesn't change any meaning. However knowing the hz value it will give a clue on the matter. With hz, you notice the difference, perform extra test an d comparison, find out the context, or you will catch the pattern or procedure, and in music you will define the scale. It will support you to eliminate with confidence certain flavour of a singer. There is a value, I suppose.

Comment: if 15 voice existes the representative notes be, of couse given as an output. The time is relative, some one going fast and other slow. The repetition will also reflect on this issue. In case the person sings the same coice for 15 seconds, the output is only one. Thanks Reinligh.

Comment: My point is that what you are asking the software to do is a very complicated artificial intelligence problem. Transcribing music is still most accurately done by a human being. It may be possible for you to write AI software that interprets a moving FFT, but this will only be reliable for single-line music. To accurately transcribe most music, you will need to generate multiple Hz values for multiple peaks on the FFT for a single point in time, and you will not be able to figure out which one is the melody without the use of a human musician.

Comment: @ NReilingh - can we list the actual transfer? 1- a song, 2- transfer into FFT, 3- transcribe into hz. If we need only these 3 steps to perform how can yiu say a lot of activities. If as you said the steps are too maney. Would mind to tell me why is combursome. I appreciate it.

Comment: Your 1st observation on the 1st line was to deal with FFT in order to transfer a sound into hz. Do you mind to elaborate that argument please. Part of the solution seems lying there. Where do you see steps that evaluate the hz value in order to catch a way to control sound manually? And if does, what are main (2 or 3) steps that lead to convert the sound into hertz value?

Comment: Let me rephrase about the data. 1st step - The recorded song is a solo. If it is in a group stike the notes are the same for all. So there is no song in 3 or 3 or 4 voices all together. 2nd step - the chant should be transcribed into hz. How maney steps you think it needs to convert a song of 3 minutes into a hz value. I would like to head your guess. 3rd step - how can I recollect the data in list into a  word or excel or acces file document? These are the keys that help me toward a solution. Reiling you pointed interesting topics. Thanks

Comment: The illustrations you sent me on SOUND TEMPERED table, the sound is measured in hz value and waveform value. Let me see if I can past it here: "A3 220.00 156.82 A#3/Bb3 233.08 148.02 B3 246.94 139.71 C4 261.63 131.87" (these are 4 group of notes, the note, the hz value and the wave form value). Which way the easy process to get an output from a recorded vocal sound? I s it easy to catch the hz or waveform value? Once we reach to one of this the second will be derived, I think. NReilingh, wIting for your comment.

Comment: I addressed issues in directing the sound to filter its hz from a software. That was my petition at first. Now with any like java script, is there a way to convert the raw sound into hz is my question. Hope I have narrowed the question. Thanks

Comment: Look, now you're asking me to design your program for you. I've answered the _software recommendation_ question to the best of my ability. You need to read the Wikipedia page on the [FFT algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) yourself. When you fully understand it and have done some experimentation on your own, you will be able to make your own decisions about how to structure your program.

Comment: as you reiterated it is true what you said in terms of theory. However, since I am interested to verify songs that takes more than days of time, I know I can not proceed with such long and intricated activities. Sorry if i didn't rephrase that well. I am looking into a built into a software. If you can do it and we agree on price that is an administrative job. My approach is, if there any software that performs this activity. I know there are some, but I don't conitinue with that software because I need more performances, like from hz value to shift into the word processor.

Comment: And from there on to database, and so few or two more activities. I understand to do my research wnd not relegate that. If you kn8w that there are good procedures you are welcome. Therefore, I am still looking for simple procedures that garantee the result and or software that are availabke in the market. I am asking if there are software so I can buy one for my project. Talking about procedure, as you listed them on the front page, it is ok. But we to verify what the advantages among the two ways. To calculate the comfortable one of the two, we are stilll digging for any proof.

Comment: As my interest, I checked the Audocity software. In the spectrum, there is a choice to check the frequency value. From I got from the spectrum is these data: The frequency in hz value and the level db. The frequency in this data is a constant number, like a counter. While the level db is discrete number. From these 2 data what conclusion can you deduct? Thanks.

Comment: On the other hand, the data of Hz appears on the spectrum. But it is linked to the mouse movement, and it is a very shaky point that almost difficult to pin point to it. If there better ways good, but from this template very difficult to control all the data of any song, because too lengthy and inefficient task.  At this point, a software or similar virtual reality software would be better to implement. Even though with the audocity software essential result may be achievable, to get a straight forward results from the song data toward a hz value cannot be resumed from the audocity template.

Comment: Berhane - you are entirely misunderstanding the point here. What NReilingh has told you is: there are applications that can help you find the frequencies present **at a point in time** in a piece of music. You will need to work out a way to step through your music, extracting all those frequencies as you go. Audacity provides a visualisation - **you** will need to script a tool like MaxMSP to actually extract the frequencies. You may find you also need to calculate the length of the notes from your sampling.

Comment: I cannot say tha I understood all Mr Reilingh said. He might be a professional person who got already the answer. To do my homwork I went back to revise the audocity. The spectrum mentioned above gave me a constant value of Hz in reference to db. This could not be of help. I can say may be there are tricks to trigger, & if it was good to share. This part was good because I could export the file in Excell. The value of Hz and db were available for test, but something is missing, i.e. the function that leads to the correct Hz value.I appreciate Rory,I am trying to focus into not blaiming anyone.